# Type casting issue with generic Entity in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, templates, dart-pub

I have the following code using Parse Server SDK to read/write objects from the backend.

```
abstract class BaseTest<T> {
  T fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map);
}

abstract class Entity<T> implements BaseTest<T> {
  Map<String, dynamic> _dataMap = {};

  @override
  T fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    _dataMap = map;
    return this as T;
  }
}

class ConcretEntity extends Entity<ConcretEntity> {
  ConcretEntity();

  factory ConcretEntity.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ConcretEntity()..fromMap(map);
  }
}

abstract class RepositoryBase<T extends Entity> {
  Future<T> get(String id);
}

class ConcreteImplRepo<T extends Entity> extends RepositoryBase<T> {
  @override
  Future<T> get(String id) async {
    var objectResponse = await ParseObject("DishDataV2").getObject(id);
    if (objectResponse.success) {
      T entity = (T as Entity).fromMap(objectResponse.result);
      return entity;
    }
    throw Exception();
  }
}

void main() async {
  await Parse().initialize(
    "COOK_APP",
    "http://localhost:1337/parse",
  );

  ConcreteImplRepo<ConcretEntity> aa = ConcreteImplRepo();
  ConcretEntity enity = ConcretEntity();
  var kk = await aa.get("xfqON6WuOW");

  print("Hello World");
}
```

Something weird is happening here `T entity = (T as Entity).fromMap(objectResponse.result);` I will get this error:

```
Unhandled exception:
type '_Type' is not a subtype of type 'Entity<dynamic>' in type cast
```

But the weird part is that `T` is in my example is `ConcretEntity` which extends `Entity<ConcretEntity>` so it should work, but the error said that `T` is not a subtype of `Entity`.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: "the error said that T is not a subtype of Entity." No, the error said that `_Type` (an implementation of [`Type`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Type-class.html)) is not a subtype of `Entity`.  It did not say anything about `ConcretEntity`.  `T as Entity` cannot work; `as` casts object *instances*, not types, and `T` is an instance of a `Type`, not an instance of an `Entity`.

Comment: It looks like your goal is to invoke the `ConcretEntity.fromMap` `factory` constructor, but constructors and `static` methods are not part of the class's interface.    I strongly recommend using [`package:json_serializable`](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) or [`package:built_value`](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value) and not implementing your own serialization/deserialization code. Alternatively pass around a `fromMap` callback appropriate for the type.